# Flask test_client can't handle HTTP 204 No data

Tags: python, testing, flask, http-status-code-204

I have delete endpoint, returning HTTP 204

```
@blueprint.route('/foo', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_tag(id):
    # ....
    return '', 204
```

and I want to test it

```
def test_delete_tag(self):
    resp = self.client.delete(url_for('tags.delete_tag', id=1))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 204)
```

but I got exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/tags_test.py", line 31, in test_delete_tag
    resp = self.client.delete(url_for('tags.delete_tag', id=1)})
  File ".virtualenvs/...site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 799, in delete
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File ".virtualenvs/...site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 108, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File ".virtualenvs/...site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 742, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ, buffered=buffered)
  File ".virtualenvs/...site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 659, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File ".virtualenvs/.../site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 885, in run_wsgi_app
    buffer.append(next(app_iter))
StopIteration
```

with response status 200 it works all fine. Is there way how to fix the test?

Comment: I confirm the issue on my side too. Adding `buffered=True` stop the problem, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The mining of 204 is "no content" at all, it's assume that you're not going to add any body in that response.

Answer (score 1):

small flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/foo', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_tag():
    print("i got", request.form['id'])
    return '', 204

@app.route('/foo2/<id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_tag2(id):
    print("i got.. .", id)
    return '', 204

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in ipython qtconsole; i did this:

```
In [3]: from app import app

In [4]: from flask import url_for

In [5]: c = app.test_client()

In [6]: with app.test_request_context():
   ...:     rv = c.delete(url_for('delete_tag2', id=55))
   ...:     print(rv.status_code)
   ...:     
i got.. . 55
204

In [7]: rv = c.delete("/foo", data={"id": 555})
i got 555

In [8]: rv.status_code
Out[8]: 204
```

Comment: hmmm, behave same for me. Thats at least narrows possible places where can be problem.